# Android Studio/IntelliJ - Field/Variable/Constant creation shortcut

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

Trying to go from eclipse where you can go over some text, do ctrl-1, select something like create/extract constant, and then it will automatically create it.

The equivalent is roughly ctrl-shift-alt-T, then select from the listing.

Unfortunately in Android Studio, I keep getting:

```
"cannot perform refactoring. unknown expression type."
```

**Is there any way around this?**

What confuses me is that the little lightbulb pops up, and I can click on that, and create constant through there works (and it knows the correct type, etc.).
*An alternative acceptable answer would be how to automatically select the little lightbulb that pops up with a keyboard shortcut*

Comment: alt-enter seems to be the way to access the lightbulb in most cases.

Comment: furthermore, it looks like most of the refactoring auto-completions must go from an actual method call or something that produces, and then will create the name and the variable at the same time.  (ie. can't go from just a name in an inferred location).  The alt-enter seems to be the closest to the functionality I desire.

Comment: Refactoring/extract/field or CTRL+ALT+F to extract field and Refactoring/extract/constant or CTRL+ALT+C to extract constant works for me. But maybe I don't exactly understand your problem. Do these shortcuts work for you?

Answer (score 7):

Select the String that need to be converted into the constant 
use CTRL + ALT + C (on Windows) or Cmd + ALT + C (on Mac OS)
For more details I think the flowing link gonna help you [Extract Constant](http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2015/01/23/android-studio-tip-1-extract-constants/)

Answer (score 1):

Select the String that need to be converted into the constant use CTRL + ALT + C (on Windows) or Cmd + ALT + C (on Mac OS)
For more details I think the flowing link gonna help you Extract Constant

Answer (score 0):

On mac, Android Studio/Preferences/Keymap, search "constant", add or replace with any hotkey you want. I used Eclipse hotkey so it is not available by default.

[image]